# Open spark readstream to Amqp provider

Tags: databricks, azureservicebus, amqp, spark-structured-streaming

We are using Azure Service Bus and Databricks. We would like to store messages coming in to Service Bus in Databricks. We are using DLT pipelines in Databricks, which return a spark read or readStream object.

Question: Is there any provider that would allow opening spark.read or readStream to an AMQP endpoint like service bus?

Service bus also supports getting the next message through an http call. Can dlt pipelines support that?